# Reference Request: Error correction code for a random projection

Tags: reference-request, it.information-theory, coding-theory

I'm interested in a variant of the Binary Channel, where the bits aren't *flipped* with some probability, but rather they are *completely erased*. Output words therefore vary in length.

I'm quite sure that this subject is well researched, and all I need is the correct search term.

Comment: sounds like some kind of edit distance metric. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the term is [deletion channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletion_channel). As the Wikipedia article says, this "should not be confused with the binary erasure channel".

Comment: Yes, and a place to start could be Mitzenmacher's survey (2009): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.152.1315

Answer (score -2):

The term you're looking for is: Binary Erasure Channel. And here's the link: [Binary Erasure channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_erasure_channel).

Comment: In an erasure channel the erased bits appear as question marks, so for instance $10111$ could be corrupted to $10??1$, whereas for a deletion channel, the bits are removed entirely, so we would receive $101$.